# Facebook Like button Comment box, Empty comments

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

When a user clicks on Like button a popup appears if he types some text in the Comment Box the story appears in his timeline but if he dont type anything it will not post anything to his wall , how can i force it to post even if the text is blank ?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: you can't. Why would you post nothing to his timeline?

Comment: not nothing , i ll post an image with some open graph tags, it will just dont have a user comment.

Comment: You can i ve seen it , i just want to know how they do it.